# McKelvey and Zavoina's pseudo-$R^2$ score range

Tags: goodness-of-fit, probit, pseudo-r-squared

I am trying to build a probit regression model. Looking for some proper goodness of fit indicator for my model I read that McKelvey and Zavoina's pseudo-$R^2$ could be the best index for this purpose.

I tried to look for the score range of this index but I coudn't find anything about that. Do you know how to interpret McKelvey and Zavoina's pseudo-$R^2$? How wide is the range of values that it can assume?

I have a McKelvey and Zavoina's pseudo-$R^2$ = 0.157. I guess it is not so high.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! How is this value calculated?

Comment: I just used a preset function on R from the package DescTools. The function is PseudoR2 (which = "McKelveyZavoina"), and I got 0.157. As I read, McKelvey and Zavoina's pseudo R^2 is the one that, among other pseduo R^2, behaves  most like the standard OLS R^2. So I assume it should range between 0 and 1, as OLS R^2. But I am not sure.

Comment: And what would you consider a good $R^2$ in a regression problem?

Comment: If pseudo-R^2 ranges between 0 and 1, as OLS R^2, then it would be better to have an higher score (close to 1). Of course, if you mean that interpreting only one pseudo-R^2 is non-sense I would add that other models delivered a score around 0.15 and 0.16. Therefore all models are close but, first of all I would like to have a range if there is one. This could help to assess the score independently from other scores